# Updating control value of HTML Textbox in VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, object, textbox

I have an excel with over 100 HTML textboxes that need their control values to be updated to match cell references. I am getting a runtime error 1004, Application or object defined error.

I have tried all combinations of the below to no avail.

- Test 1 from
  https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/71462-copy-text-from-html-text-box/
- Tests 2 and 3 from
  https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/addressing-htmltext-object-in-spreadsheet-vba-script.4014065/

  ```
  Sub test()


  'test1
          Dim TB As OLEObject
      'test2
          'Dim TB As TextBox
      'test3
          'Dim TB As msforms.TextBox

      Set TB = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes(HTMLText99)
      'Set TB = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(HTMLText99)

      TB.Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 7)
      'TB.Text = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 7)
      'TB.Object.Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 7)
      'TB.Object.Text = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 7)
  End Sub
  ```

Interestingly, if i just do a simple code (see below), the visible value of the HTML box changes as expected, but once I click "Detail view" in the developer tab, the visible value reverts back to the control value which I can see when I open properties on the HTML textbox.

```
ActiveSheet.HTMLText99.Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly how your objects are named but this might give you some ideas:

```
Dim o, i As Long
For Each o In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    If TypeName(o.Object) = "HTMLText" Then
        Debug.Print o.TopLeftCell.Address, o.Name, _
                    o.Object.HTMLName, o.Object.Value
    End If
Next o
```

FYI there's a difference between a control's "runtime" and "design-time" properties: if you make a change to the textbox it will revert when you enter Design mode on the sheet.